# Terminating 'ravcpl64.exe' causes sound to become disabled

Tags: windows, audio, realtek-hd-audio

On my computer, which is a netbook, there is a process related to Realtek HD Audio called `ravcpl64.exe`.

When I terminate that process, the sound is completely turned off. However, Realtek HD Audio is installed on my laptop as well and there is no such process on Task Manager.

Why is `ravcpl64.exe` there?

Comment: Is your netbook using 64 bit version of Windows and laptop is on 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the process `ravcpl64.exe` is using by 64-Bit version of Windows. If your laptop is running on 32-Bit version then this process renamed there with the name of `rthdvcpl.exe`.

After considering with **Oliver Salzburg** I got some new ideas from him.

> As this could be the problem of that you are talking about the software being installed on the other system as well other system has a Realtek driver control center thing as well. Thus, you identifies that it has the same software.
>
> Of course, it isn't the same software at all. It could be largely different versions.
> So it is not at all surprising that there are differences in the names of the binaries.
> It may be the equivalent software, but not the same.

Comment: mmh, you are correct that the laptop has 32-bit OS.(Vista). However, on the laptop there is no rthdvcpl process as well. Despite that, it runs fine. Whereas on the netbook, when i terminated the process, the sound is turned off.